# Is the ref property the only way to access the DOM in a ReactJS application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is the `ref` property of components the only idiomatic way to "escape the world of ReactJS" and interact with the DOM directly when working in a ReactJS application?

Clearly I could do something like `document.querySelector` in `componentDidMount`, but other than that...

Comment: `findDomNode` is another way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    componentWillMount(){
        console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        console.log(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this))
    }
    render(){
        return(
             <div>wefewfewfewfwefewf</div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,document.getElementById("app")
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can use `ReactDOM.findDOMNode`. It takes a react component and returns a underlying `dom` element.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the ref property of components the only idiomatic way to "escape the world of ReactJS" and interact with the DOM directly when working in a ReactJS application?

No, you can escape using the [`React.findDOMNode`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode) function also, though Facebook recommends using `refs` instead.

Outside of `refs` and the aforementioned method, I dont think there are any other *React* methods for escaping. This being said, you may also use vanilla javascript to do this as well though this is not preferred.